# Swift. Pass delegate for UIImagePicker as argument

Tags: swift, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

A class ImagePicker contains and UIImagePicker:

```
class ImagePicker {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var delegate: AnyObject?

    init(delegate: AnyObject?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func pickPhoto() {
       self.imagePicker.delegate = delegate
       // The line above gives an error "Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a value of type 'protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?'

       delegate?.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

A UICollectionView inits the image picker:

```
let imagePicker = ImagePicker(self)
imagePicker.pickPhoto()
```

So this does not work because of the error mentioned above, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate cannot be of type `AnyObject?`. It has to be of type `protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?` instead:

```
class ImagePicker {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    weak var delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?

    init(delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    ....
}
```

You should also make it a `weak` property to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Actually of what class is the delegate then since it is only defined by it's protocol adherences but no class is set for itself?

Comment: The whole point of using delegate protocols is that you do not specify a class for the delegate. This way all objects that implement the methods defined in the protocol can act as delegates. Regardless of their class.